# Iteration numbers with True False condition

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Please HELP!!

I have a list:

```
a = ['False', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True']
```

I want to generate iteration number if it's False the number continues and if it's True the number stays.
I Try this code:

```
result = []
x = 1
for i in a:
    while i == 'False':
        result.append(x)
        if i == 'True':
            x+=1
            continue
            result.append(x)
        x += 1
```

it's just keep running and did not show any output.
the desired output will be `[1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6]`

I have no idea what's wrong with it
Thanks

Comment: Why would `i` change, inside an iteration of the for-loop? Once it's `'False'`, you're stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: `result.append(x)` after `continue` will never get executed

Comment: your while statement is a loop man... it will run forever in case there is `'False'`

Comment: how? i iterate value in the list. then when i == 'False', each number is stored in result then when the iteration found i == 'True' the number stay same and keep continue until the list ends

Comment: could someone provide the correction code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another version of this (with the output behaving as required by OP):

```
def weird_sequence(some_list):
    prev = None
    number = 0
    for item in some_list:
        if prev is None:
            prev = "False"
        if item == "False" or prev == "False":
            number += 1
        yield number
        prev = item
```

Usage:

```
>>> list(weird_sequence(['False', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True']))
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 5):

This can actually be solved pretty nicely with `accumulate` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import accumulate

a = ['False', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True']

print(list(accumulate(1 if i == 'False' else 0 for i in a)))
```

Same result as gtomer, which I believe is the correct output.

Comment: the output should be [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6]. that code will give [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]

Answer (score 2):

See this code below:

```
a = ['False', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True']
result = []
x = 0
for i in a:
    if i == 'False':
        x+=1
    result.append(x)

print (result)
```

Note that if I understood your text, your desired output is not correct

Comment: My code gives the correct output: [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]

Comment: it should be [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6]

Comment: But if you count the Falses then why is it 1,2 and then 3 and not 2?

Comment: when the value changes also +1 on the iteration then if the next value is still 'True' then it stays

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is that once i takes a value of "False" it goes in a (infinite) while loop and never comes out. Bcz the value of i never changes in the while loop itself.

```
result = []
x=1
for i in a:
  if i=="False":
    x+=1
  result.append(x)
```

This should work for you